# Get Podio Item Subscribers

Tags: podio

There does not seem to be a documented API endpoint to get an item's subscribers. However, the UI shows this information (hover over the "Following" badge in the top bar and it shows people following the item by name).

[image]

Since the UI is doing this, there must be an API endpoint to get this info.

The only documented API endpoint that I can find is [/subscription/{ref_type}/{ref_id}](https://developers.podio.com/doc/subscriptions/get-subscription-by-reference-22408) which only shows the subscriptions for the user making the API request. I need all users just like the UI shows.

Anyone have any clues on this?

Answer (score 0):

Curious, I did an experiment on this and found that your list of followers can be found in the 'created_by'.'name' of the {"comments"} and {"revisions"} arrays. Using the {"subscribed_count"} value as a measurement, get a distinct "users" list for the arrays and if the counts match, your now apart of the "golden company".

If you get a count mismatch, then in the same GET item call there is the "presence" array that gives you the "user_id" causing the variance.

[presence array example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyvkm.png)

Comment: That's an interesting approach that gets about 50%. Unfortunately it doesn't get anyone that's following the item because they chose to follow it or were [at]mentioned.

I guess one could parse all comments for [at]mentions, but that still leaves the direct followers out.